# very slow insert into SQL temp table in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I found a terrible bottleneck in this one procedure. No idea why this little block of code is running so slowly here. If I comment this one block out, the entire thing takes around 7 seconds to do its job. This block adds over a minute and a half.

Here's the definition of #TempFC:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempFC (
    NoticeID int, 
    AttyID int, 
    AFN9 varchar(9), 
    FirstPubDate smalldatetime, 
    MortgagorName varchar(255), 
    PropAddress varchar(255)
)
```

Here's the definition of #NoticeIDs

```
CREATE TABLE #NoticeIDs (
    NoticeID INT, 
    CircuitCourtPubDateID INT, 
    CircuitCourtAdjournmentPublicationDate SMALLDATETIME
)
```

At the point where this runs, #TempFC is empty and there are only 2 rows in #NoticeIDs. A minute and 1/2 to insert 2 narrow rows into an empty table.

```
INSERT INTO #TempFC (
    NoticeID, 
    AttyID, 
    AFN9, 
    FirstPubDate, 
    MortgagorName, 
    PropAddress
)   
SELECT              
    tN.NoticeID,
    tN.AttyID,
    tN.AttyFileNum9Chars as AFN9,
    tN.FirstPubDate,
    tN.MortgagorName,
    tN.PropAddress
FROM
    dbo.tblNotices tN
    INNER JOIN #NoticeIDs ON #NoticeIDs.NoticeID = tN.NoticeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblAttorneys tA ON tN.AttyID = tA.AttyID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblParentAttorneys tPA on tA.ParentAttorneyID = tPA.ParentAttorneyID 
WHERE
    tPA.PubAffTiming = 2
```

If I comment out the "INSERT" line and just run the select (with a RETURN after it), it takes a few seconds to run all the code above and then the select. If I comment out the SELECT and add a "VALUES" line to the INSERT statement, that runs fast too.

I also put all the above into a separate query window and ran it as is. it ran very fast, sub second. In addition, I put it into a single small stored procedure all by itself and it ran lightning fast as well.

I'm lost as to why this would slow down so drastically here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

CREATE TABLE #TempFC & INSERT INTO #TempFC

with SELECT...into #TempFC

and also try to replace '2' with @x